# C#: Time consuming operation enqueue in background task?

Tags: c#, background, queue, task

i´m struggeling with some background processes.
There are two methods in my console app. A `private static async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> GenerateSomething()` and the other method send something to a webserver.
The GenerateSomething-Method takes much more time, than the `private static async SendSomething()` Method.
Now i had the idea to run the GenerateSomething() method multiple times in the background and fill a queue of each task with the returns.

I´ve already started with programming, but i don´t know how i can run multiple GenerateSomething() methods in the background, while the SendSomething() is working on it´s self.

This is my latest result:

```
    class Program
    {
        private static Queue<Dictionary<string, string>> QueueOfDicts = new Queue<Dictionary<string, string>>();
        private static int batchCount = 5000;
        private static int queueMinThreshold = 10;
        private static long genCounter = 0;
        private static long dictCounter = 0;
        private static Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetSomething().Wait();
        }
        private static async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> GenerateSomething()
        {
            var Dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();

           // Here I do some calculations which takes approximately 30 seconds
            for (int i = 0; i < batchCount; i++)
            {
            // some calculations
            }
            dictCounter++;
            Console.WriteLine($"Added Dict #{dictCounter} with {batchCount} to the Queue.");
            return Dict;
        }
        private static async Task SendSomething()
        {
            long time = 0;
            long avgTime = 0;
            var counter = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                var url = "https://.............";
                var web = new Web(url);
                var address = "xxxxxxxxxxx";
                var service = new Service(web, address);

                if (QueueOfDicts.Count > queueMinThreshold)
                {
                    var result = QueueOfDicts.Dequeue();
                    Console.WriteLine("QueueCount: " + QueueOfDicts.Count);
                    try
                    {
                        stopwatch.Start();
                        // here i wait send the webresponse, which takes about 5 seconds
                        stopwatch.Stop();
                        time = stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds;
                        stopwatch.Reset();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        await SendFailedMessage(ex);
                        GetSomething().Wait();
                    }

                    var index = 0;
                    foreach (var res in result)
                    {
                        //do something
                        index++;
                    }
                    genCounter += batchCount;
                    avgTime += time;
                    counter++;
                    if (counter >= 100000 / batchCount)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Average " + avgTime / counter);
                        counter = 0;
                        avgTime = 0;
                    }
                    Console.WriteLine("{0} analyzes made -- LastCall: {1}ms", genCounter, time);
                }
                else
                    QueueOfDicts.Enqueue(await GenerateSomething());
            }

            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("-----------ERROR----------: \n End with error: \n" + ex.ToString());
                await SendFailedMessage(ex);
                Console.WriteLine("Querytime:" + time);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
    private static async Task<Message> SendFailedMessage(Exception ex)
    {
        var Bot = new TelegramBotClient(".....");
        return await Bot.SendTextMessageAsync("...", "Something went wrong: \n" + ex);
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me, how i run the `private static async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> GenerateSomething()` in background multiple times, while the `private static async SendSomething()` do it´s own job in the meantime?

Hopefully you´ve enough informations to help me.
Thanks to everybody who can help me with this little project.

Answer (score 0):

For simplicity I removed most of Your code that has to do with Your internal classes.

Simplest way for multiple tasks in parallel and in the background is currently to use async-await pattern, that is using `Tasks`.
Below You have an minimal example of such thing, without going into additional details like locks, thread-safety etc.

I would recommend to take an interest in Task parallel library of C#, it will help you a lot.

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Collections.Generic;

class Program
{
    private static int batchCount = 5000;
    private static int queueMinThreshold = 10;
    static async Task Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Run 10 times
        var arr = new Task<Dictionary<string, string>>[queueMinThreshold];
        for (int i = 0; i < queueMinThreshold; i++)
        {
            int id = i;
            arr[i] = Task.Run(async () => await GenerateSomething(id));
        }

        // Do whatever in the meantime
        // Execute some other function call, like SendSomething()
        // ...


        // Finally await result of long-running operations (When all of them are finished)
        await Task.WhenAll(arr);

        // And, if needed, access those reults
        var firstResult = arr[0].Result; // non-blocking call - it is already finished.
    }

    private static async Task<Dictionary<string, string>> GenerateSomething(int id)
    {
        var Dict = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        // Here I do some calculations which takes approximately 30 seconds
        for (int i = 0; i < batchCount; i++)
        {
        // some calculations
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Added Dict #{id} with {batchCount} to the Queue.");
        return Dict;
    }
}
```